# Html code clearner

Tags: java, html

Is there any library or method to input a String with html code, and which has a return value another String without this html code, just the information???
I am watching libraries such JTidy, or HtmlParser, but I don't know how to use it!
Something easier???

Comment: Please correct all typo's. It is difficult to read

Comment: So basically you want something to strip html tags out of a string?

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Screen Scraping Tools Written in Java](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/screen-scraping-tools-written-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all HTML tags from the given String.

```
String html = //...
html = html.replaceAll("</?.*?>", "");
```

But if you're looking to screen-scrape, you can use [XPath](http://w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) to pull out specific parts of the HTML:

```
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(html));
DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(source, result);
Node root = result.getNode();

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String value = xpath.evaluate("/the/xpath/expression", root);
```